# Advice needed on simple neural network

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network, backpropagation

So, I am quite new to neural network programming, just starting to understand the basics of how it works. I am programming my own simple one in python, using Numpy, as a learning experience mostly.
Here is my batch evaluation, backpropagation, sigmoid, prime sigmoid, and cost functions:

```
def Sigmoid(self, x):
    return 1.0 / (1.0 + np.exp(-x))

def PrimeSigmoid(self, x):
    return self.Sigmoid(x) * (1.0 - self.Sigmoid(x))

def _OutputCost(self, aResult, tResult):
    return [(a - t)**2 for a, t in zip(aResult, tResult)]

def _BackProp(self, tData, tGoal):
    derB = [np.zeros(b.shape) for b in self.gBiases]
    derW = [np.zeros(w.shape) for w in self.gWeights]

    activation = tData
    activations = [tData]
    zL = []
    for b, w in zip(self.gBiases, self.gWeights):
        z = np.dot(w, activation) + b
        zL.append(z)
        activation = self.Sigmoid(z)
        activations.append(activation)

    cost = self._OutputCost(activations[-1], tGoal)
    ps = self.PrimeSigmoid(zL[-1])
    deltas = cost * ps
    derB[-1] = deltas
    derW[-1] = np.dot(deltas, self.gWeights[-1])

    for l in range(2, self.gLayerCount):
        z = zL[-l]
        sp = self.PrimeSigmoid(z)
        deltas = np.dot(deltas, self.gBiases[-l + 1]) * sp
        derB[-l] = deltas
        derW[-l] = np.dot(deltas, self.gWeights[-l])
    return (derB, derW, np.average(cost, 0))

def _EvalBatch(self, batch, tSpeed):
    derB = [np.zeros(b.shape) for b in self.gBiases]
    derW = [np.zeros(w.shape) for w in self.gWeights]
    costL = []
    for d, g in batch:
        dDerB, dDerW, cost = self._BackProp(d, g)
        costL.append(cost)
        derB = [nb + dnb for nb, dnb in zip(derB, dDerB)]
        derW = [nw + dnw for nw, dnw in zip(derW, dDerW)]
    self.gBiases = [b + (tSpeed / len(batch)) * nb for b, nb in zip(self.gBiases, derB)]
    self.gWeights = [w + (tSpeed / len(batch)) * nw for w, nw in zip(self.gWeights, derW)]
    self.gCost = np.average(np.array(costL), 0)
```

So far it works ok, but for some reason I cant get one thing working properly:
It doesnt ever reduce the weights (at least the last layers' ones). So it gets stuck in a way, where it increases the weights a lot at the start, jumps over the "correct" values, then increases it less and less over time, but never actually decreasing them in order to bring balance again. I have played with the learning speed, but it doesnt seem to fix the problem, it just happens slower.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. This is not a code-writing or tutoring service. It is not possible to provide a specific answer without you providing sufficient information to understand your problem. Please see: [Why is Can someone help me? not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)  for more details.

Comment: @itprorh66 this question strikes me as much more specific than your comment implies: "for some reason [...] It doesnt ever reduce the weights (at least the last layers' ones)." That's very narrowly: why doesn't this implementation of a neural network ever reduce the weights in the last layer?